# Printf splits a string at spaces using Bash

Tags: bash, printf

I'm having some troubles with the `printf` function in bash.
I wrote a little script on which I pass a name and two letters (such as "sh", "py", "ht") and it creates a file in the current working directory named "name.extension".
For instance, if I execute `seed test py` a file named `test.py` is created in the current working dir with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

So far, so good, nothing fancy: I'm learning shell scripting and I thought this could be a simple exercise to test the knowledge gained so far.
The problem is when I want to create an HTML file. This is the function that I use:

```
creaHtml(){
        head='<!--DOCTYPE html-->\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t</body>\n</html>'
        percorso=$CARTELLA_CORRENTE/$NOME_FILE.html
        printf $head>>$percorso
        chmod 755 $percorso

}
```

If I run, for instance, `seed test ht` the correct function (`creaHtml`) is called, `test.html` is created but if I try to look into it I only see:

```
<!--DOCTYPE
```

And nothing else.
This is the trace for that function:

```
[sviluppo:~/bin]$ seed test ht
+ creaHtml
+ head='<!--DOCTYPE html-->\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t</body>\n</html>'
+ percorso=/home/sviluppo/bin/test.html
+ printf '<!--DOCTYPE' 'html-->\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta' 'charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t</body>\n</html>'
+ chmod 755 /home/sviluppo/bin/test.html
+ set +x
```

However, if I try to run `printf '<!--DOCTYPE html-->\n<html>\n\t<head>\n\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t</body>\n</html>'` from the terminal, I see the correct output: the "skeleton" of an HTML file neatly displayed with indentation and everything. What am I missing here?

Comment: Basically, quote your variables. Don't use `echo -e` as it's non-standard. `printf` will do what you want when you add the quotes.

Comment: Just to be perfectly sure, I have to double quote when I refer to variables, such as `printf "$var1"` , right?

Comment: Double quotes will evaluate variables inside.  Single quotes are for literals that will not be evaluated.

Comment: ok, I think I got it. I'm learning Python too, so this whole "double quotes/single quotes" thing is a bit confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `echo -e` instead of `printf`.  `printf` is for printing formatted strings. Since you didn't protect `$head` with quotes, bash splits the string to form the command.  The first word (before first white space) forms the format string.  The rest are just arguments for things you didn't specify to print.

```
echo -e "$head" > "$percorso"
```

The `-e` evaluates your `\n` into newlines.  I changed your `>>` to `>` since it looks like you want this to be the whole file, rather than append to any existing file you might have.

You have to be careful with quotes in bash.  One thing can become many things.  This actually makes it more powerful, but it can be confusing for people learning.  Notice that I also put the file name `"$percorso"` in double quotes too.  This evaluates the variable and makes sure that it ends up as one thing.  If you use single quotes, it will be one word, but not evaluated.  Unlike Python, there is a big difference between single and double quotes.

If you want to use `printf` for compatibility as @chepner pointed out, just be sure to quote it:

```
printf "$head" > "$percorso"
```

Actually that is much simpler anyway.

Comment: Excellent! It works like a charm. Thank you for the blitz answer, as soon as I can I will accept your answer, right now stackoverflow says that I can accept in 6 minutes.

Comment: `printf` is recommended over `echo -e`, if only as a good habit to get into. `echo`'s behavior varies greatly from one shell to another, while `printf`'s behavior is well-defined by POSIX.

Comment: @chepner good point. I added that.  It is also simpler that way. I should have done it that way in the beginning.

Comment: One further point. Since the first argument to `printf` is always processed for format strings, you should avoid using parameter expansions whose contents are unknown. (Consider `printf '%s'`, for example.) Use `printf '%s' "$head"` to be safe.

Comment: @chepner I guess the issue here is that there are `\t` and `\n` contained within `$head`.

Comment: That's a problem with `creaHTML`; it should embed actual tab and newline characters in the value, not digraphs that need to be processed specially.

Comment: @ chepner yes, indeed I should use regular white spaces instead of \t or \n.. I used these because I couldn't figure out why things weren't working