# printf in shell show only the first word

Tags: string, shell, printf

I am making a program shell (#!/bin/sh) and the problem is that printf show just the first word of the string param.

This is an extract of code to simplify for you:

```
#!/bin/sh

test="Good morning"
printf "\n"
printf $test
printf "\n"
```

This code outputs just `Good`.

Comment: Why using `printf` here, when you don't want to do any formatting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printf splits a string at spaces using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35270131/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double-quote your variable to avoid getting Word-splitting by shell

```
printf "$test"
```

Moreover, the general syntax for `printf` like `C` would be to have

```
printf <FORMAT> <ARGUMENTS...>
```

The text format is given in `<FORMAT>`, while all arguments the format string may point to are given after that, here, indicated by `<ARGUMENTS…>`.

The problem you are seeing is because an unquoted variable in `bash` invokes the word-splitting. This means that the variable is split on whitespace (or whatever the special variable `$IFS` has been set to) and each resulting word is used as a glob (it will expand to match any matching file names). Your problem is with because of the splitting part.

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Only the first argument is the format string, the others are additional arguments to be formatted. [Just like in C.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43574/how-is-printf-in-c-c-a-buffer-overflow-vulnerability)

```
printf '\n'
printf '%s' "$test"
printf '\n'
```