# Bash: Printf replaces space with newline

Tags: bash, shell

Below shell script introduces newline when it encounters space.

```
countries = "Brazil Russia India"
printf "Countries are %s" $countries
```

Output  comes as:

```
Countries are Brazil
Countries are Russia 
Countries are India
```

Instead it should come as

```
Countries are Brazil Russia India
```

Is there any way to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: how are you able to use spaces around `=` in variable declaration? you can also use `echo "Countries are $countries"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printf splits a string at spaces using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35270131/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quote the variable to make it a single argument.

```
printf "Countries are %s" "$countries"
```

In general, you should *always* quote your variables unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to solve your problem. To understand why Bash behaves the way it does, read the explanation in [this answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) The gist of it is, unquoted variables with spaces (or other special characters) do not behave as a whole string. So be careful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
countries="Brazil Russia India"
printf "Countries are %s" "${countries}"
```